# how do I generate/replace my TD tags with data from my JSON file

Tags: jquery, html

```
<table id="administration" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="6" class="caption">Administration</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th><span>Name</span></th>
                <th><span>Monday</span></th>
                <th><span>Tuesday</span></th>
                <th><span>Wednesday</span></th>
                <th><span>Thursday</span></th>
                <th><span>Friday</span></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="lalign">John Smith<br><span style="color: navy;text-align: center;">Leader</span></td>
                <td>Main Campus AM<br>Main Campus PM</td>
                <td>Main Campus AM<br>Main Campus PM</td>
                <td>Main Campus AM<br>Main Campus PM</td>
                <td>Main Campus AM<br>Main Campus PM</td>
                <td>Main Campus AM<br>Main Campus PM</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="lalign">Vannessa Smith<br><span style="color: navy;text-align: center;">Lead Developer</span></td>
                <td>Main Campus AM<br>Main Campus PM</td>
                <td>Main Campus AM<br>Main Campus PM</td>
                <td>Ex. Campus AM<br>Main Campus PM</td>
                <td>Main Campus AM<br>Main Campus PM</td>
                <td>Main Campus AM<br>Main Campus PM</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="lalign">Jane Phillips<br><span style="color: navy;text-align: center;">Git Officer</span></td>
                <td>Main Campus AM<br>Main Campus PM</td>
                <td>Main Campus AM<br>Main Campus PM</td>
                <td>Main Campus AM<br>Main Campus PM</td>
                <td>Main Campus AM<br>Main Campus PM</td>
                <td>Main Campus AM<br>Main Campus PM</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

This is my HARD CODED table

I am using a JSON file that contains the schedule for the person. My question is what is the best/easiest approach to replace the entries like **Main Campus AM** from my file

I also want to mention that I have 5 more tables but each table has a different id (this one above is administration)

I can access the schedule for each person by using this javascript code

```
v.mondayAM
v.mondayPM
v.tuesdayAM
v.tuesdayPM
v.wednesdayAM
v.wednesdayPM
v.thursdayAM
v.thursdayPM
v.fridayAM
v.fridayAM
v.saturdayAM
v.saturdayPM
```

Comment: Better to go for some light weight rendering frameworks like jsRender/knockoutJs/reactjs etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the names are being hard-coded, you might as well assign an id to the `<tr>` such as `<tr id="leader">`

Then you can more easily use something like:

```
    $("td").filter(":contains('Campus AM')").remove()
    $("#leader").append($("<td>").html(v.mondayAM + '<br>' + v.mondayPM));
```

If this is an object you can use a for...of loop on the append statements.

Comment: its hard coded now. I am moving the data into JSON objects so it won't be hard-coded

Comment: With the objects, it will be so much easier to create what you want dynamically. 

You can empty `<tbody>` and create rows based on user data, assign classes then add columns etc, etc.